# Why does an embedded video in bootstrap mobile autoplay before the homepage displays?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design, html5-video, mp4

I have made a responsive [website](http://www.southwalesneon.com) using bootstrap, and I have a media page with an embedded video. My code for it is this...

```
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">


                <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"  src="video/yellow-bend1.mp4" width="600"></iframe>
                </div>


            </div>
```

It displays fine on large screens, but when I visit using my mobile, the video opens and autoplays in my video app before the home page displays, and you have to close the app to see the site. Is there a way to keep it fixed on the media page on mobile displays?

This is my first experience embedding video, and all the answer Ive searched for seem to be asking the opposite of what I need.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3">

    <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">

        <video src="src="video/yellow-bend1.mp4"" controls></video> 

    </div>    
</div>
```

Comment: Amazing. I'll give that a try now!

Comment: I tried adding that code, and the video disappeared from the page on desktop and phone. I had a hunt around on here and it said the code should be &autoplay=0. If I do that, the video still autoplays. I tried wrapping the iframe with a video tag, and I just got an error message. It is probably something glaringly obvious I've missed (it usually is), but  I can't find the problem.

Comment: Try this it should defo work now if this works then adding the auto play should be resolved ill add it in my previous answer

Answer (score 0):

I found this that works:

```
<video autoplay=0 controls>
<source src="video/yellow-bend1.mp4" type="video/mp4"  />
</video>
```